# Redirect If - Javascript

Tags: javascript

The redirect isn't working when "this._try == 1"?

Here's the full JS, however it no longer is checking the try == 1 on click, rather automatically when the window is closed.

```
function ouvre(fichier) {

  ff=window.open(fichier,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%")
  //this._try = 1;     
  setTimeout('this._try = 1;', 4000);
}


function playMovie(_try) {
  if (this._try == 1) { playsavideo(); }
  else { alert('You must share to unlock.'); }
}

function playsavideo(type) {
  {
    window.location = "http://google.com"


  }
}
```

The window is called by this...

```
<a href="#" onClick="ouvre('https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button');return false">Test</a>
```

Comment: Try moving it to the callback of setTimeout?

Comment: That does not look like the code u want to show us. Some pieces are commented out, and why do u use `this` are you creating an object someware? show all the code?

Comment: @popnoodles his code still does not make sense, can u understand where what is this `this`?

Comment: @popnoodles I added more of the code, sorry!

Comment: @AndrewRivers someone already answered the question, but it is important that you post chunks of code as you have now, not just cut and paste lines of code. Errors aren't necessarily that straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use `this` as the carrier of the value / global variable.
But `this` is a "relative" variable, it always relates to an instance of an object it is in.
In your code there is no instance. and even if it was, the `this` inside the function will
refer to one thing and any other `this` outside the function will most probably refer to another thing.

While global vars are not good practice. Try this:

```
var i_am_a_global_var = false;
function ouvre(fichier) {
    ff=window.open(fichier,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%");
    setTimeout(function(){window.i_am_a_global_var=true;bobo();}, 4000);
}

function bobo(){
  if (window.i_am_a_global_var) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/" 
  }
}
```

1. define a global variable
2. when the time out happens it wil callback a closure (`function(){...}`) which will call the `bobo` function.
3. the bobo function is where redirect happens, if global var is true.

You might did this due to other logic which mught change your `this._try` but if all you wanted to do is redirect after x seconds, then the short version would be:

```
window.open(fichier,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%");
setTimeout('window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"', 4000);
```

Comment: Someone pointed out it should be `window.location.href=...` or do both work?

Comment: @popnoodles both work, but to be on the safe side, i'll edit to your version

Answer (score 1):

you can add a new function with content `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"`, then edit setTimeout('[function name]', 4000).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass function to setTimeout. And I think you should do the redirect in the function.

```
var that = this;
function ouvre(fichier) {
    ff=window.open(fichier,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%");
    //this._try = 1;
    var fn = function() {
       that._try = 1;
       window.location = 'http://google.com';
    }
    setTimeout(fn, 4000);
}
```

Comment: This works as well and it doesn't use global vars so I'm going to implement this. Thank you so much!